# JavaScript: Looping - last index of value (without using indexOf.)

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to create a function called lastIndexOf, that takes in an array and a value and if the value is present in the array it returns the last index in which it is present and if not then it returns -1 or if the array is empty is returns -1.

e.g. lastIndexOf([ 0, 2, 4, 1, 2 ], 2); would return 4

This is what I have so far but for some reason it is not producing the desired result, any advice would be really appreciated

```
const lastIndexOf = function (arr, value) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === value)  {
      return i; 
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  }
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is there some explanation for not using the built-in `.lastIndexOf()` on the Array prototype?

Comment: Anyway your function starts at the *beginning* of the array and returns as soon as it sees a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1) You return a value on the first iteration no matter what. You need `return -1` after the entire array has been looped through

2) You're looping in the wrong order, if you want the last index, you should start from the end

```
const lastIndexOf = function (arr, value) {
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (arr[i] === value)  {
      return i; 
    }
  }
  return -1;
};
```

BTW, there is a built-in function for this: `arr.lastIndexOf(value)`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use one of these functions. It depends on which one is compatible with you. You are looping through each element of an array for it and that's not good

```js
const arr = [0,1,2,5,4]

function lastIndex(arr) {
  return (arr.length) ? arr.length - 1 : -1;
}

function indexOfArrayValue(arr,value){
  return (arr.indexOf(value) > -1) ? arr.indexOf(value) : -1;
}



console.log(lastIndex(arr));
console.log(indexOfArrayValue(arr,5));
```